# JSF2: converter attribute not found:

Tags: jsf-2, migration, converters

I'm upgrading our webapp from JSF1.2 to JSF2. 
Our VDL is JSP. We are using Richfaces 3.3.3

I have a h:selectOneMenu and h:outputText that use the following property:

```
converter="SelectObjectConverter"
```

The 'SelectObjectConverter' is defined in the faces-config.xml:

```
<converter>
  <converter-id>SelectObjectConverter</converter-id>
  <converter-class>com.vc.mm.utils.jsf.converter.SelectObjectConverter</converter-class>
</converter>
```

**The converter works as expected in JSF1.2 but not in JSF2**.

Here is the error message:

> exception: org.apache.jasper.el.JspELException: /bla/bla/foobar.jsp (14,1) 'SelectObjectConverter' Cannot coerce from class java.lang.String to interface javax.faces.convert.Converter

If I use this syntax :

```
<f:converter converterId="SelectObjectConverter"/>
```

It's work!
But, as we have a lot of files with the other syntax, I would like to find the cause.

The faces-config file header has been updated to:

```
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
```

Comment: Strange. What if you replace `<converter>` entry in `faces-config-xml` by a `@FacesConverter("SelectObjectConverter")` annotation on the converter class?

Comment: What JSF impl/version exactly? What servletcontainer impl/version exactly?

Comment: @BalusC, JSF 1.2 => JBoss4.2.3 with mojarra 1.2_08-b06 (in our webapp, not jboss one)   and JSF2 => JBoss 7.1.1 with jsf-impl-2.1.7 (mojarra embedded with jboss)

Comment: @BalusC, mmm.. you answered to fast and I had trouble with the return key... see my edited answer above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our ear/lib, there was a jbpm.jar and juel**.jar.

juel.jar is an open source implementation of EL. Removing all "juel" jar fixes the problem.

I guess juel was providing the (wrong) EL implementation to JSF.